# update statement with limit

Tags: sql

```
update accounts a
left join users b on
    a.user_id = b.user_id
set `sold` = '1' where b.country = 'UA' AND a.site = 'od'
```

How to limit this query?

Tried

```
update accounts a
left join users b on
    a.user_id = b.user_id
set `sold` = '1' where b.country = 'UA' AND a.site = 'od' LIMIT 500
```

but get error Error : Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

Comment: You can't limit an update, what you *can* do is limit a `select` and update the results of that select. That will require a stored procedure or a function AFAIK (but I'm not a DBA...).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update accounts a left join users b on a.user_id = b.user_id
set 'sold' = '1'
where b.country in
(select country from
(select country from users where
country = 'UA' order by user_id asc limit 500) tmp) and 
a.site in
(select site from
(select site from accounts where
site = 'od' order by user_id asc limit 500) tmp2);
```

See this for further details on the select limit statement.

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php

Answer (score 0):

I will first use a CTE table(temp table) to hold your limit query, then perform an update using that table:

```
With LimitQuery As
(
select * from  accounts a
left join users b on
    a.user_id = b.user_id
where b.country = 'UA' AND a.site = 'od' LIMIT 500
)

update LimitQuery 
set `sold` = '1'
```